# Slick Slider zero width in hidden container (Bootstrap tab)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

I'm using a Bootstrap 4 tab navigation to view different sliders inside the tab panels.

It works well for the active tab. But the sliders in the inactive tabs have an width of 0 (`.slide-track`). So there is a display problem until I'm start to navigate through the tabs. After that, the width is set and the slider looks fine.

Is there any way to set the width of the slide track to the correct size?

```js
$('.slider-home').slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
});

$('.slider-profile').slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
});

$('.slider-contact').slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
});
```

```css
.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: blue;
}

.tab-pane {
  padding: 2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      <div class="slider-home">
        <div>
          <p class="h1">home 1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">home 2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">home 3</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">home 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      <div class="slider-profile">
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 3</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 4</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 5</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
      <div class="slider-contact">
        <div>
          <p class="h1">contact 1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">contact 2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">contact 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vv4j3uz2/5/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because when a container is hidden it's not possible for its child elements to calculate their widths.

To get around this you could instead instantiate the `slick()` controls when the tabs are shown. Then the widths can be calculated. Try this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function() {   
  $($(this).attr('href')).find('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    arrows: true
  })
}).first().trigger('shown.bs.tab');
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vv4j3uz2/7/)

Comment: sorry... It's me again. I tried to make it work with more than one tab content area. but after that, the slider breaks again. Here's my example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403464/slick-slider-breaks-after-tab-change-and-slider-nav-doesnt-sync Has it something to do with the `.first()`argument?

Comment: OK, if I change `.first()` to `.eq()`, the navigation/sync between two sliders works again. If I put both sliders in one tab panel, the sliders in the hidden containers are unfortunately still broken.

Comment: for preventing error it's better to use this:
`$($(this).attr('href')).find('.slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick({...`

becuase if not add this you will see:
slick.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to manually refresh the initialized slider after it's shown.
Here's a demonstration:

```js
// Initialize sliders.
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
});

// When a tab is shown...
$('.nav-link').on('shown.bs.tab', function() {

  // ... select the corresponding tab pane ...
  let $tabPane = $($(this).attr('href'));

  // ... and refresh its slider.
  $('.slider', $tabPane).slick('refresh');

});
```

```css
.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: blue;
}

.tab-pane {
  padding: 2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      <div class="slider slider-home">
        <div>
          <p class="h1">home 1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">home 2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">home 3</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">home 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      <div class="slider slider-profile">
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 3</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 4</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">profile 5</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
      <div class="slider slider-contact">
        <div>
          <p class="h1">contact 1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">contact 2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="h1">contact 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For reference, see:

- [Bootstrap Nav Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events)

  > **shown.bs.tab**
  >   This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown. Use event.target and event.relatedTarget to target the active tab and the previous active tab (if available) respectively.

- [Slick Slider Methods](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#methods)

  > // Manually refresh positioning of slick
  >   `$('.your-element').slick('setPosition');`

  [`.slick('refresh')`](https://github.com/staskjs/vue-slick/issues/83) also works.

- If you're using [Bootstrap's Collapse component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/), it  has equivalent [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events):

  > **shown.bs.collapse**
  >   This event is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).